# In Unix, how could I count lines of code not starting with white space?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
test1:
  1. samplinggggggg
  2. samplinggggggg
  3. samplinggggggg

test2:
  1. samplinggggggg
  2. samplinggggggg
  3. samplinggggggg
  4. samplinggggggg
```

In above case, the number of lines not starting with white space should be 2. How could I achieve this in Unix using `wc -l` or better ways?

Comment: `grep '^\S' ...|wc -l`? filter out the spaced lines, count what's left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using grep with the `-c` switch, to output a count:

```
grep -c '^[^ ]' file
```

The pattern matches a non-space character at the start of the line.

To include other types of white space characters (e.g. tabs), use `[^[:space:]]` instead:

```
grep -c '^[^[:space:]]' file
```

...or if your version of grep supports it (e.g. GNU grep), use `\S` instead, as a shorthand for `[^[:space:]]`:

```
grep -c '^\S' file
```

Comment: Could you explain to me why it can skip blank lines?

Comment: The reason is that each of the patterns match _one_ non-space character at the start of the line. If the line is blank, then there are _zero_ characters, so the pattern cannot match.